# Maui Ios not working after testing hot restart

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, maui

Hobbyist developer here.

I have managed to publish an App for android Platform. Maui Tuner. Hooray!

I made the solution with VS and Maui platform. So it is easy to port it to apple too, right?

Well my experiences have been that not at all. VS for MAC is a total disaster IMHO. All kinds of weird behavior. I managed to deploy half of the app to my test iphone but afterwards the environment went totally weird and I was not able to restore the somewhat working system.

So I went the PC windows route. Connected to mac and deployed from windows. Interestingly that did work. Everything was about fine. It was only that the build+deployment took about 5 minutes. So pretty slow but working.

So I tested hot reload. Straight deployment from windows to iphone. Deployment went fine and fast but app was not working. App uses skia so that is maybe a library that is static and not supported by hot restart. Maybe some other static libraries also I dont know.

So I tried to revert back to previous step which was working. I disabled hot restart.

Now the deployment takes only about one minute and solution goes to black screen. Tried uninstalling itunes. Rebooting . Some weird behavior in VS and not able to continue project. This is frustrating.

Any tips?

-Jani

Update to this. VS project file seems to hold the malfunctioning stuff. I tried a previous project and now there is some progress. Now I only need to make all the changes to this new/old project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixes to Try:**

1. Given that it is only this one project that is messed up, its likely a setting that VS is holding for that project.

- Each solution has a hidden `.vs` folder. Quit VS. In Windows Explorer, Delete that folder. Start VS again.
  (If don't see folder, make sure Windows Explorer is showing hidden folders)

2. If that doesn't fix it, then:

- delete all `.bin` and `.obj` folders in the solution. This is like "Clean Solution", but more thorough.

NOTE: Usually when something is messed up in a project, steps to try are: a) Clean Solution; b) If still bad, Delete `.bin`/`.obj`; c) If still bad, delete `.vs`. But in the situation here, its probably `.vs`, so suggested that first.

3. Its possible that the bad setting is stored on the device (or emulator), associated with the app.

- On the device's home screen, delete the app. This deletes all associated information.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I managed to proceed with the older project. So Next time I will try these.